# Non-standard calendars in pandas

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, calendar, astropy

I am trying to use the Python pandas library with timeseries data that go beyond AD 1.  Pandas' datetime objects apparently use the numpy [datetime64](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.datetime.html) object, whose range is limited to 1/1/1 - 9999/12/31.

It is possible to index a DataFrame with a non-datetime index, but let's face it: the real strength of pandas (e.g. resampling) shines when rows are indexed by a proper datetime object. Without the resample() method I may not need pandas at all.

Several Python projects have implemented alternate calendars, in particular astropy and FlexiDate, but neither generates a datetime object.  I just learned that Numpy folks [do not envision supporting non-standard calendars anytime soon](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/6207#issuecomment-210092663).

Before posting a ticket on the pandas project GitHub, I am hereby appealing to the StackOverflow hive mind: do you know of a not-too-clunky way to generate a datetime index that pandas will recognize and that handles non-standard calendars?

Comment: Would a TimeDeltaIndex suit your needs? http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timedeltas.html#using-the-timedeltaindex

Comment: An astropy.time.Time instance has an `datetime` attribute. That still won't give you standard `datetime` objects with a negative year though.

Comment: Just so you know, pandas datetimeIndex has a limitation from `1677-09-22 00:12:43.145225` to `2262-04-11 23:47:16.854775807`. You should use periodIndex instead. http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/gotchas.html#gotchas-timestamp-limits

Comment: Why not just offset the dates so they are in range e.g. declare dates that are in range but keep some kind of year offset as a separate column so know what your intended dates represent?

Comment: @su79eu7k: periodIndex does work, but only for years between  1 AD and 9999 AD. I don't know how to go beyond that.

Comment: @EdChum it's a pretty clunky solution. I might use it if only I didn't have to represent 800,000 years.  Is there any way to bypass this limit? If I try to go before 1 AD or beyond 9999 AD I get  `DateParseError: year is out of range`

Comment: @Evert thanks for the tip. It seems both astropy.time and pandas implement the python [datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime) module and inherit its limited range.